# adding class row instead of col-md-12 makes the div not cover the entire width of the screen. Can someone help me understand the reason behind this?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The row class in bootstrap, when added to a div, should cause it to cover the entire width of the screen. It's working in most divs but seems to fail in some cases. Can someone point out my errors? I've tried reading the documentation. What have I missed?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>My Clock App</title>
    <script src="knockout-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
    <script defer src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="openBar" class="row">
            <span id="openButton" data-bind="click: openNav">&#9776; open</span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <h1>My World Clock</h1>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div data-bind="foreach: countries">
            <div  class="row throw">
                <--adding row instead of col-md-12 causes issues-->
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3>Pikachu</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <h5 data-bind="text: day"></h5>
                    <p data-bind="text: date"></p>
                    <p data-bind="text: time"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <h5 data-bind="text: capital"></h5>
                    <p data-bind="text: currency"></p>
                    <p data-bind="text: coor"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 languages" data-bind="foreach: lang">
                    <p data-bind="text: name"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 altName" data-bind="foreach: alts">
                    <p data-bind="text: $data"></p>
                </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 flag">
                        <img data-bind="attr:{src: imgSrc}">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you create a plunk for the same ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question should contain [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can do this by creating a Stack Snippet.

Comment: I've never used Plunk before. Seems useful. I'll try it for future references, thanks.

Comment: Apologies, I read the minimal, complete and verifiable example article and I'll try to adhere to the standard in futures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to nest a `.row` within a `.row`. `.row` elements have a negative left and right margin that matches the left and right padding of `.col-` elements. `.col-` elements **should be** the child elements of a `.row`. This allows the outside edge of the columns gutter to line up as expected.

Since you are attempting to `.row` you're going to have a total of `-30px` for the left and right margins, pulling your content to the outsides further than wanted.

Demo of double nested `.row`.

```css
@import url(  'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">12 Columns</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="row">Row Row</div>
</div>
```

Notice that the second row should show `Row Row`, but it doesn't. The left negative margin pulls the first `Row` outside of the viewports view.

Since `.row` isn't simply a descriptive feature and applies styling with real consequences I suggest removing the class from the DIV.